# writing a simplified version of the unix chmod in c

Tags: c

This is my code, but its is not working well. Please i need help. Even if i write ./mychmod 777 text.txt for example it blocks all the rights instead of the inverse.Thanks in advance

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<fcntl.h>
 #include<sys/stat.h>
 #include<sys/types.h>
 #include<unistd.h>

 int isFile(const char *ct){
 int test=0;
 test=open(ct,O_RDONLY) ;
 if(test==-1)
 return 1;
 else
 return 0;
 close(test);
 }

 int main( int nb , char ** args){

 if(nb<3)
 exit(1);
 int nbs=(int)(atoi(args[1]));


  int i=2;
  while(i<nb)
  {

    if(isFile(args[i])==0){
    chmod(args[i],nbs);
    if(chmod(args[i],nbs)==0)
      printf("success\n");
    else
      printf("failed\n");
    }
    else 
    exit(1);



    i++;
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hint - 777 is an *octal* number, not a decimal number.

Comment: Another hint: close your files before returning from the function.

Comment: Another hint: don't run chmod on the same item twice.

Comment: thanks its now working. i used strtol() to convert to base 8 since atoi() only translates decimal

Comment: Please add this as **answer** and tick it to indicate that it resolved the problem so the question does not appear in '*no answers*' / '*unsolved*' listings anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Chmod traditionally takes numerical values in octal, so if you want to enable all access rights, you use 0777 (decimal value 511). You're passing in 777 and parsing it as a decimal value with atoi, so you end up with octal value 1411, which is probably an error because it's greater than 0777. At best, it's not at all the permissions you meant to set.